# Optimize speed of Mysql JOIN query

Tags: mysql, database, join, indexing, query-performance

I have 2 tables called `T1` made of 1.6mln of rows and `T2` made of 4.6mln of rows with with one-to-many relationship.

The CREATE STMT of `T1` is:

```
CREATE TABLE `T1` (
  `field_1` text,
  `field_2` text,
  `field_3` decimal(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_4` decimal(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_4` decimal(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_5` text,
  `field_6` text,
  `field_7` text,
  `field_8` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_9` text,
  `field_10` text,
  `field_11` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The CREATE STMT of `T2` is:

```
CREATE TABLE `T2` (
  `field_1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_2` text,
  `field_3` text,
  `field_4` text,
  `field_5` text,
  `field_6` text,
  `field_7` text,
  `field_8` text,
  `field_9` text,
  `field_10` text,
  `field_11` text,
  `field_12` text,
  `field_13` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I don't have set **any kind of indexes** or any particular constraints for now, but the `T1.field_1` should be my ideal key and can be joined with `T2.field_2` field.

If I decide to make a JOIN like:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
JOIN T2
ON T1.field_1=T2.field_2
WHERE T1.=2130100;
```

The benchmark is really high. 
This is the EXPLAIN:
[image: explain]

So I'm just trying to understand what could be some possibile improvements:

- Add some index
- Change the type of the input fields?
- Maybe add a primary key?

Comment: Comparing tables by column type `TEXT` is a bad idea.

Comment: Historically VARCHAR was faster than TEXT.

Comment: Yes - All of them.

Comment: @JoopEggen - In some situations, varchar and text have the same performance; in some situations, `TEXT` is significantly slower (involving an extra disk hit).

Answer (score 2):

In you where condition you missed  the column name i assume the columns is named your_col

Starting form mysql 5.0.3 varchar can be up 65,535 so you could try using varchar instead of text when possibile

for indexing  there are  limitation on the size of the  index  max key length is 767 byte  ( assuming   3 bytes for each utf8 character. so about 250 utf8 char )

the column candidate for indexing must respected  these limit 
if this is possible  then you could 
add index  on

table  t2 colums fiedl_2

and on

```
table t1 a composite index on  column (Your_col, field_1)
```

these are the columns involved in where and ON clause

```
  SELECT * FROM T1
  JOIN T2
  ON T1.field_1=T2.field_2
  WHERE T1.Your_col=2130100;
```

Comment: Yes, switch to `VARCHAR` where practical, but no, don't blindly use `VARCHAR(65535)`; that will be as bad as `TEXT`.  Pick reasonable max sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `latin1`, switch `t1.field_1` and `t2.field_2` to `VARCHAR` of no more than 767.  Use the shortest value that is not likely to be exceeded.  Do likewise for all the other `TEXT` columns.  (If you need >767, stick with `TEXT`.)

Then add two indexes:

```
T1:  INDEX(??) -- whatever column you are using in the `WHERE`
T2:  INDEX(field_2)
```

If the column in T1 is an INT, then `2130100` is OK.  But if it is `TEXT` (or soon to be `VARCHAR(..)`, then quote it:  `"2130100"`.  The should prevent a surprising and unnecessary table scan of T1.